# TypeKit font converts ss to ß

Tags: css, opentype, typekit

On a website with German content we are integrating a custom font via Adobe TypeKit (`Basel Neue`) using the standard script. However the font will display *any* occurrence of `ss` as `ß` instead - which does not make sense in many cases (e.g. `Wasser` will be displayed as `Waßer` etc.).

I am not sure if this is an OpenType feature and thus can be controlled via CSS settings. I was unable to identify such an OpenType feature [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/open-type-syntax.html) at least. I also can't find any info on the web for such a case - only info about the other way around (`ß` to `ss`).

Does anyone have any idea why this happens or whether a TypeKit setting can control this behavior?

Comment: Note that you can always tell what is being applied by inspecting your text and instead of looking at the CSS, looking at the `computed` rules. For instance, for the text in your question SO has no explicit rules and dev tools shows `font-variant-ligatures: normal`. Knowing this, we can now force `font-variant-ligatures: none` to prevent a font's ligatures from kicking in by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like ligatures issues.
Try this:

```
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: none;
font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;           /* <common-lig-values> */
font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;        /* <common-lig-values> */
font-variant-ligatures: discretionary-ligatures;    /* <discretionary-lig-values> */
font-variant-ligatures: no-discretionary-ligatures; /* <discretionary-lig-values> */
font-variant-ligatures: historical-ligatures;       /* <historical-lig-values> */
font-variant-ligatures: no-historical-ligatures;    /* <historical-lig-values> */
font-variant-ligatures: contextual;                 /* <contextual-alt-values> */
font-variant-ligatures: no-contextual;              /* <contextual-alt-values> */
font-variant-ligatures: contextual;                 /* <no-historical-ligatures> <common-ligatures> */

/* Global values */
font-variant-ligatures: inherit;
font-variant-ligatures: initial;
font-variant-ligatures: unset;
```

from MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures

Comment: Thx, through trial and error I found out that the value `none` and `no-common-ligatures` will prevent this behaviour.

Comment: to be honest I wasn't sure, it just reminded me of ligatures... :) lucky guess

Comment: Yes, I also thought it ought to have something to do with ligatures. However I find this default behaviour very peculiar, thus I wasn't sure - and I hadn't yet found (or try to find) a complete list of possible settings for this CSS property.

Comment: Fonts are full "playbooks" when it comes to typesetting, including instructions on which typographical features should be applied "by default", as well as which to apply "per script". Basel Neue presumably comes with a default list of typographical adjustments that includes common ligatures, and probably extra rules for things like `s+s→ß` when it's being asked how to typeset German text (fonts are the typographical equivalent of a game ROM. They contain *all* the rules, the font engine just sets the bootstrap parameters and then passes in string inputs to be turned into shape output)